# How to UPDATE multiple times off one connection OleDb

Tags: c#, web-services, ms-access

I am trying to update an Access database with information I have passed to a [WebMethod] from multiple txtbox's on a website.

```
[WebMethod]
public string changePersonalInfo(string email, string name, string id, string address, string contactDetails, string password, string question, string answer, string loggedInEmail)
```

I am passing all information to it weather it has a value or not.

```
 if (email != "") //Wont execute if there is no value
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE BuyerInfo SET [emailAddress] = '" + email + "' WHERE (emailAddress = '" + loggedInEmail + "')";
            }
            if (name != "")
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE BuyerInfo SET [name] = '" + name + "' WHERE (emailAddress = '" + loggedInEmail + "')";
            }
            if (id != "")
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE BuyerInfo SET [id] = '" + id + "' WHERE (emailAddress = '" + loggedInEmail + "')";
            }
        //etc. It goes on for a few more.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                   

        conn.Close();
```

The problem is when I run the website it only updates the data from the last txtbox on the website (so in other words the last variable that has a value). How do I fix this, or if there is maybe a better way to do it.
P.S Keep in mind I am new to Web Services.
Thanx

Comment: It looks like you are updating the same row now matter how many updates you run because the `WHERE` clause is the logged in user email. So the last update is the one that will stick.

Comment: Thanx bud. Got it to work

Comment: Access is not recommended as a database for a website. Eventually you will have more problems. You should be using a server type database.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this post, I believe the cause of the problem was you were creating 'cmd.CommandText' multiple times (thus overlaying), yet only executing one time - which would execute the LAST command you created.